# what's the alternative method for typeFactory.arrayType(xxx)?

Tags: json, jackson

as jackson 1.8, typeFactory.arrayType(xxx) is deprecated, what's method I should use for express a type safe array such as int[]?

Answer (score 3):

You need to access TypeFactory using ObjectMapper.getTypeFactory(), then call instance methods. Change was needed to allow certain types of type handling overrides (specifically for Scala extension module).
Or you can instantiate a stand-alone TypeFactory if you have no access to ObjectMapper (or related objects, serializer/deserializer provider)